# ws.message is undefined Error, Web Socket response

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I am python developer but i need to see my websocket output from browser.

```
function startSocket() {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765/")
    ws.onopen = function(event) {
        ws.send("Sent this from client.js")
        console.log(typeof ws.message);
        console.log("test")
        console.log(ws.message)
    }
}
startSocket();
```

this is my clien.js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
  <head>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->
    <link type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="client.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

and this is my html file.
I am sending a string from my web socket and i want to see inside of a browser.
When i run this html, my web socket is starting to work but my logs are saying undefined.

This is my Log Output

```
client.js:6 undefined
client.js:7 test
client.js:8 undefined
```

Comment: You're trying to use `ws.message` before you've received anything.

Comment: I am doing ws.send() and this get request going to my websocket. And websocket has a websocket.send function for sending response for client.

Comment: `onopen` should be `onmessage`.

Comment: `ws.message` is the message that has been received from the server, not the message you sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

bind to the correct event handlers

```js
function startSocket() {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765/");
    ws.onopen = function(event) {
        console.log("connection opened");
        ws.send("Sent this from client.js")
    };
    ws.onmessage = function(message) {
        console.log(typeof message);
        console.log("test")
        console.log(message)
    };
};
startSocket();
```